# Is there a way to automate the merging of groups in photoshop, one by one?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, photoshop-scripting, automation, script

In a file, I have about 10-20 groups of independent layers each. 
Is there a script/action that identifies each group and merges them one by one?
As of now, it takes me a lot of time waiting on a group to merge before merging the other one.

Comment: Are these groups of layers actually grouped or...?

Comment: One screenshot is worth of thousands words. Please add more info about your file structure and before-after results so people wouldn't waste time guessing what you need exactly.

Comment: Command/Ctrl-E wis the shortcut, You can create an action to merge, then select next group below/above.